# GWT : Showing alert message on top,regardless of other alerts

Tags: java, css, gwt, z-index

Consider the following case.

Having 3 dialog boxes  in my application.

```
final DialogBox alert1 = new DialogBox();
final DialogBox alert2 = new DialogBox();
final DialogBox alert3 = new DialogBox();
```

then I am calling to show these dialog like

```
alert1.show();
alert2.show();
alert3.show();
```

Here is my question:

Regardless of order I calling the `show()`  function,I always want to show the `alert2`  on the top.  as of now `alert1`  is showing on top,alert 2 in middle, and `alert3` in the back.

Have quick look for the problem here with three dialog's.

---

[image]

With little Css knowledge tried to set `Z-index` for the `alert2`  like

```
DOM.setIntStyleAttribute(alert.getElement(), "zIndex", 101);
```

Still know effect.Its showing in the same place and unable to click the links on `alert2`

Thankful for any hints.

Comment: suresh this is problem with z-index of dialog box's css!! please cross check with it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be on the modal feature of DialogBox (inherited from the PopupPanel it exteds). By default it prevents mouse and keyboard events for widgets not contained by the dialog. So because alert3 has been displayed the last, it disables alert2 events.

If you want a DialogBox with the modal attribute disabled set modal to false:

```
 alert1.setModal(false);
```

or call this constructor:

```
 final DialogBox alert1 = new DialogBox(true, false);
```

Comment: No,No.Modal use I know.problem with `z-index`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set css for alert2 like position: fixed, z-index: 101? Remember that you need position specified. If you want to specify order of other alerts just give them some position and lower z-index.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with dialog box's **css**. Please check whatever css applied for each **dialogbox** those have a different **z-index** or same.